# Подскажите, какие есть особенности верстки под mac устройства? Может есть какая нибуть спецификация?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, sass

Дело в том что на винде верстка отображается нормально, а на маке нет.

Comment: Да, особенности есть. Сафаря == тот же IE, по сути. Смотришь что отображается неправильно, и исправляешь (автомагии вродекаг нет, увы). Еще caniuse помогает в процессе верстки (когда хочешь использовать какую-либо новую удобную штуку, но не уверен поймет ли ее тухлояблочный браузер) - это вместо спецификации, типа. Плюс autoprefixer от PostCSS, чтобы вручную вендорные префиксы не писать каждый раз.

Comment: ...Плюс, сжечь гульпъ и взять инструменты поновее, которые хотя бы тот же автопрефиксер уже сами умеют запускать (например, Vite для сборки под современные браузеры ок, если готов мириться с отсутствием sourcemaps для стилей).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Обязательно попробую.

Comment: Покажите скриншоты что-ли, что у вас отображается по-разному...

Comment: " которые хотя бы тот же автопрефиксер уже сами умеют запускать" - в чём проблема использовать автопрефиксер с gulp? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer